# why isn't this pulling data from 7 days back?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong here. This is what I have:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE agentassigned = 'agent' AND reminder ='$reminder date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+7 day"))' ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will not execute the PHP code you sent it in the query.

That's probably not what you meant to do. Instead, concatenate the result of the `date()` call.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE agentassigned = 'agent' AND reminder ='$reminder " . date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+7 day")) . "' ORDER BY firstname";
```

Based on your comments, you actually want something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  contacts
WHERE
  agentassigned = 'agent'
AND
  reminder_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Where you need to add a column `reminder_date` to your table which contains the date of the reminder. You don't want to try to parse it out of a string like you're doing. It's slow and wrong.

Comment: The date in the reminder is 2011-07-29 and it's still not showing up using that code...??

Comment: That's 3 days from now, not 7 days from now, unless you're a time traveler :)

Comment: so, what am I doing wrong with my code, I'm wanting to display all reminders due in the next 7 days?

Comment: 2011-07-29 is 3 days from now. Your query asks for rows for the date 2011-08-02 (7 days from now).

Comment: You're checking for date equality. Check for <= instead. Or better see Dan's comment on my answer on the best approach.

Comment: with you now, sorry...so what do I use if I want to display all reminders due in the next 7 days?

Comment: I have amended my answer. You need to change how you're storing the reminders. You need to store the date, as a single atomic piece of data, so that you can query by it.

Comment: What if I wanted to just pull for the span of that week, for example just this week july 24 - july 30 ?

Comment: I understand how it works if I put the days in myself like you did Dan, what I'm trying to do is have it display only the reminders for the current week (mon-sun or sun-sat doesn't matter)

Comment: Get the dates with `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday'))` and `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday + 7 days'))`. Now put them in the query.

Comment: I'm really a newby here, how would I do that?

Comment: The same way you did it in your question and in my answer to your question. You already know how to do this.

Comment: Ok I did it like we had and I'm getting an error that it's not a valid mysql result. `$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder BETWEEN date ('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday')) AND date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday + 7 days')) ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());`

Comment: Telling you why you can't do that and how to fix it was my original answer to your original question (scroll up then scroll right and see how what I wrote differs from what you wrote).

Comment: so ive tried several ways and still getting an error not a valid MySQL result resource for `$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder ='$reminder " . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday')) AND date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday + INTERVAL 7 day')) . "' ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
` and also `$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder >= BETWEEN date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday')) AND date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday + INTERVAL 7 day')) ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());`

Comment: OK. STOP. You're attacking code without understanding what you're doing and it's not getting you anywhere. First, to do any of these things, you need a separate date column, as has been said several times before. You can't do it with your current reminder column which doesn't contain a date but some string and some date in a text field. Then, you need to actually look at the syntax of my answer and realize why it works. Read the strings chapter of the PHP manual and understand how strings work and how to concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interpolate a function call inside a double quoted string.  Instead do the function call first and save the result into `$date`:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+7 day"));
$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE agentassigned = 'agent' AND reminder ='$reminder $date' ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error:  ' .mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this...the date in the reminder is set to 2011-07-29 and it's still not pulling the reminders using that code...??

Comment: What if I wanted to just pull for the span of that week, for example just this week july 24 - july 30 ?

Comment: @joshua76 You will need to post examples of what your table data looks like, since you have the `$reminder` variable inside the query - we must assume it's not a datetime column.

Comment: it's a date column not a datetime column. my table is ID,reminder,firstname,lastname

Answer (score 1):

Because your query seems to look 7 days into future. Try "-7 day" instead of "+7 day".

Comment: that's what I want to pull all reminders for the next 7 days.

Comment: Ah ok - your title doesn't say that. See the other answers then, but you'll need <=, not = if you want the next 7 days instead of just the 7th day.

Comment: To do that you should be storing the date in a DATE type column, not as part of a string in a varchar/text column. Then you can simply ask the database for the rows `WHERE somedate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY`.