# mysql script not working for date

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why isn't this pulling data from 7 days back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838440/why-isnt-this-pulling-data-from-7-days-back)

Here is what I have, it keeps returning all reminders regardless of the date. Can anyone help guide me?

```
$reminder=$_GET['reminder'];

$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last sunday + INTERVAL 7 DAY "));

$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder = '$reminder $date' ORDER BY firstname") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error()); 

$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Comment: Could we have your database schema?

Comment: `last sunday + INTERVAL 7 DAY` is not a syntax `strtotime` can parse. You're mixing PHP and SQL syntaxes. Your second line makes no sense (assign this string to a variable or die and print a MySQL error? you haven't sent MySQL any queries to produce an error yet). **Stop creating new duplicate questions when you still haven't understood the answer to your existing one.** You're wasting others' valuable time.

Comment: does this help? column date - type datetime, column reminder - type datetime, column ID - type int(20) - auto_increment, column firstname - varchar(30)

Comment: thanks, Dan. Just trying to learn here!

Comment: If this were your actual code and that your actual schema, this query would return 0 rows, not all rows. You're not helping yourself here. Slow down and debug your own code, one line at a time. You should know before you asked this question that if you print out the value of `$date` it's going to say `1969-12-31`, and you don't have any rows with that date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime is amazingly powerful, but it can't parse a MySQL date selection syntax. If you want 7 days after last sunday, "sunday" works. You can also do, "last sunday + 7 days".

I don't know what `$reminder` is (are you sure you need to add the date to the reminder variable?), but this will work for your `$date` variable:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("sunday"));
```

As an aside, this is deadly:

```
$reminder=$_GET['reminder'];
$query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder = '$reminder $date' ".
            " ORDER BY firstname");
            // or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error()); <-- line is always true...
```

Look up Bobby Tables to understand why that first line should be:

```
$reminder=mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['reminder'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
WHERE reminder = '$reminder' AND date_column = $date
```

Answer (score 0):

the sql you have written is

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder = '$reminder $date' ORDER BY firstname
```

i think it should be like as

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE reminder = '$reminder' AND date='$date' ORDER BY firstname
```

but still it depends on your schema so just by printing your query & executing in mysql-prompt or phpmyadmin will give you good idea about troubleshooting.